# How to Add Generated Dagger Module to a Component

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, android-jetpack

I am currently building a library that generates interactors so lets say this is the interactor interface

`interface DeleteProductUsecase :EitherInteractor<None , None, Failure.SubmitionFailure>`

This interface will be annotated with this annotation:

`@WorkiUsecase(ProductRepository::class)`

With annotation processing, I'm generating a class that implement the interface like this:

```
class Generated_AddProductUsecase @Inject constructor(couroutineDispatchers: CouroutineDispatchers, val repo: ProductRepository) : DeleteProductUseCase
```

And a module that will provide our interactor:

```
@Module abstract class WorkiModule {
        @Binds
        abstract fun provideGenerated_AddProductUsecase(): AddProductUsecase
}
```

so the problem is I need to access the module to add it to the `appComponent` but in compile time the module generated is not yet generated so I can't access.  it

Comment: Do you know the package and name of the generated module?

Comment: of course i know because i am the one generating that module

Comment: this [project](https://github.com/square/AssistedInject#usage-with-dagger-2) tackles the same issue, have a look on its code to see how they generate the code for "AssistedInject_PresenterModule.class", that file is not available until you compile the project

Comment: thank you i am checking the project and i think  it handle the same issue .